# MySQL functions to remove characters from the beginning and end of a string

Tags: mysql

I've just implemented some online quiz software that will allow employees to take required post-training quizzes on our company intranet site and I've successfully set up the software to write the results to a MySQL database. I've also designed a php page that will allow supervisors to search the results of the quizzes so that employee training can be verified, however, there is one column which has been giving me trouble when the results are displayed.

In the database "training" there is a table named "questiondata". This table holds the quiz questions, the employees' responses, and the time they spent on each question. I need to display the questions along with the employees' answers as part of the supervisors search results, however, the testing software prefixes every question in the column "QuestionReference" with "Question # " and appends a suffix with the question ID (which changes for each quiz and quiz question); e.g.

```
"Question # Have you ever danced with the devil in the pale moonlight? (1868656583-10)"
```

I have been able to remove the "Question # " with

```
SELECT SUBSTR(QuestionReference, 11, 100)
```

and the suffix ID's with

```
SELECT LEFT(QuizName, Length(QuizName)-15)
```

Or

```
SELECT SUBSTR(QuestionReference, 11, 100)
```

But I haven't figured out a way to remove both the prefixes and suffixes at the same time. I'm pretty new to databases and connecting them with PHP and I've searched and searched without being able to find a solution.

Comment: Can you just post what you have now, and what you want as result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about combining the solutions you found by applying them one after another?

```
SELECT SUBSTR(LEFT(myField,LENGTH(myField)-15),11)
```

Which means "start from position 11 and cut 15 chars from the end"

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! I had tried nesting functions like that and just could NOT get it to work. That did EXACTLY what I needed it to. I had actually held off on posting because it seemed like a simple problem and I was sure I could figure it our without bugging the community but I finally got tired of slamming my head against the wall.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(QuestionReference, 11, LENGTH(QuestionReference)-11-15);
```

And you can TRIM - not to have additional spaces:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(QuestionReference, 11, LENGTH(QuestionReference)-11-15));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to remove `prefix` & `sufix` from string, but if both `prefix` and `sufix` are same then use `BOTH` on `TRIM`

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING "Question #" FROM "Question # Have you ever danced with the devil in the pale moonlight? (1868656583-10)");

SELECT TRIM(TRAILIING "(1868656583-10)" FROM "Question # Have you ever danced with the devil in the pale moonlight? (1868656583-10)");
```

**EDIT :** This is the smartest way to do that, i know your requirement is done, but try this smarter way.

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH "Question #|(1868656583-10)" FROM "Question # Have you ever danced with the devil in the pale moonlight? (1868656583-10)") as final_string;
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using two SELECTS because I wasn't sure if that would work in my php. I currently pull from the database with "$sql="SELECT SUBSTR(LEFT(QuestionReference,LENGTH(QuestionReference)-15),11), Response, ResponseSummary, Score, QuestionTime FROM qw5questiondata WHERE ResultSetID=" . $ResultSetID;"  and I wasn't sure I could have a second SELECT in there. Again, though, I've been working on this for two days and that two days represent the whole of my experience with MySQL other than installing it. I would upvote you anyway but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Ok, best of luck.@quicksilver

Comment: you can make a try my edited solution, no need to upvote my answer, but just make try once that will be a pleasurable thing if it works. @quicksilver